# How to extract individual Pipeline names from .gitlab-ci.yml file?

Tags: python, gitlab

I have two pipelines in my gitlab.yml file. I want to extract the
pipeline name individually in my python. I tried using the pyyamil
package but it does not do anything specfically to every pipeline. 
Basically,  code.py in SCAN1 pipeline should return 'SCAN1' and
code.py in SCAN2 pipeline should return 'SCAN2'.  I want to return a
value which is specific to each pipeline to be used in the code

```
script SCAN1:
    stage: test
    tags:
        - linux-default
    script:
        - bash exp.sh  & python3 code.py

script SCAN2:
    stage: test
    tags:
        - linux-default
    script:
        - bash exp.sh  & python3 code.py
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use predefined variables. Have a look at https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html

In your case you can use `CI_JOB_NAME`. It's just environment variable so in your python just get it by:

```
from os import getenv

job_name = getenv('CI_JOB_NAME')
print(job_name)
```